# Adding an icon to a C# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, icons

Bear with me here, as I've just finished building my first little app, and I'm a little fresh to all this.

I use Visual Studio's built-in publishing function to generate a nice `.exe` file, however, I'm not liking the icon it provides me with for my fresh application. I wish to change this, and after a little googling, it was concluded that double-clicking `Properties` under my project in the `Solution Explorer` would bring me to a window where I could specify my used resources.

However, it looked like this:

[image]

As you can see, the `Icon` selection is grayed out. After a little more googling, I was told it was because I had my own `Resources` folder, which I had already put resources in. And I do:

[image]

However, I do wish to be able to set an icon for my newly published application anyway. One that will add some personal flare and style to my little double-clickable `.exe` file.

How would I go about doing that now that my `Icon` selection has been grayed out in my `Properties` view?

Comment: I am not sure but try to put icon file in application root directory

Comment: Are you checking this option while debugging?

Comment: what type of project are you using ?? this usually happens in class library project

Comment: @vnikhil Tried that, and sadly it did nothing.

Comment: @amitdayama I am not.

Comment: @kyle I am not sure what to answer to this. It's an Outlook addin, if that's what you're asking?

Comment: right click your project go to Properties then Application and check your output type

Comment: @kyle My Output type is in fact a `Class Library`, yes. Is it not suppose to be? I must admit a little confusion as to what exactly the "Output type" thing is.

Comment: @ViRALiC If what you want is to set the icon of a DLL, you can't

Comment: @kyle I tried setting it to a `Windows Application` (you know, just to try) but then the publishing process started crying about a lack of a main method. Which is true, as there is no "main" method in my office pluggin.

Comment: @codroipo It is not. I just want a nice icon on my addin installer, and perhaps one that shows up when a user wishes to uninstall it from the "Add or remove programs" window.

Comment: @ViRALiC [As far as I know](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/5cd3619c-0e66-4eef-be91-0dcd3b108235/vsto-clickonce-application-icon) it is not possible to change icon of setup in Office add-in projects. You may want to consider changing the icon of setup manually using software like [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your project and select properties.

Go to the resources tab

DropDown "Add Resources" and choose add new icon.

Comment: I am not debugging. How would I go about accessing my "designer form"? Forgive me if that's an infinitely noobie question.

Comment: Edited my answer. I thought you were doing a windows project instead of outlook addin.

Comment: Yes, that's how I add an icon (like I did before!), but I am still not sure how to make said icon my application-default icon for the published `.exe`-file.

Answer (score 3):

I tried adding `Resources` folder to a project to reproduce the issue, but it didn't happen (VS 2013). Anyway, as a workaround, you can manually edit your `.csproj` file adding this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <ApplicationIcon>Resources\4.ico</ApplicationIcon>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You can add the previous lines at the same level of another `PropertyGroup`

Comment: I tried this, adding it to the existing `PropertyGroup` I found in the `.csproj` file that among other things contained my publishing path. Saved, re-published, and must sadly report that it did nothing. I went back to check that the `ApplicationIcon` hadn't been removed or something during the publish, but it was still there.